# How do I resolve a neverending attachment migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-web-services, paperclip

I'm trying to use Paperclip + Rails 3 + Heroku + AWS so i tried to add some columns to my User model to store users avatars.

My migration looks like this:

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
     add_attachment :users, :avatar
   end

   def self.down
     remove_attachment :users, :avatar
   end
 end
```

And when i run     rake db:migrate --trace it shows me this:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  AddAttachmentAvatarToUsers: migrating =====================================
-- change_table(:users)
```

But it never ends! It is a problem of my DB? The schema definition? Any idea?

Thanks!